# What was Jim Gordon's original plan and who else was involved in it?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight

In *The Dark Knight*,

> Jim Gordon is apparently killed in the line of duty.

When the city calls for Batman to be arrested, Harvey Dent turns himself in as Batman before Bruce has a chance.

During transport, the Joker and his men attack the transport. When the Joker is apprehended, it is revealed that

> Jim Gordon is not only still alive, but that he was the driver of the truck transporting Harvey Dent.  The conversation between Dent and Gordon indicates that Dent seemingly had no idea of Gordon's plan.

> *Dent*: You DO like to play things close to the chest.

It is also revealed at this point that

> Gordon's family did not know about the ruse.

The most obvious answer is that Batman and Gordon came up with the plan, but Bruce had originally intended to turn himself in.

**Who was involved in this plan, and what was the original plan (when did Gordon intend to reveal the truth)?**

Specific points to consider:

- The police were attempting to prevent any fatalities at the funeral. He had no way to know who else might be attacked there. If events hadn't unfolded exactly as they did, this plan could never be put into motion. (h/t to Deion for pointing this out.)
- No one seemed to expect Dent to turn himself in.
- While the convoy attack wasn't completely unexpected, there was no guarantee.
- If Bruce had turned himself in, Batman would not have been able to assist defending the convoy attack.
- It is only because the Joker was apprehended that Gordon's plan could be revealed.

Comment: I would add to the list that Gordon couldn't know that the Joker was going to attack at the commissioner's funeral, so it's dubious how he could have prepared to feign his death at that precise event.

Comment: Well, depending on whether or not Batman was in on the plan, he may have had a tip off that there would be a shooter - but yes, that's a good point that I'll add to the question.

Comment: @Deion, actually Gordon did know that the Joker was going to attack the mayor at the funeral because he put it in the paper.  After the commissioner is killed, there's a scene in which the Joker is heard via recording to "go to 8th and Orchard, you'll find Harvey Dent there".  Gordon and his team show up to discover two dead paramedics with a culminated name of Harvey Dent.  In the apartment, they find a news paper headlining the mayor's attendance of Loeb's memorial service the next day.

Comment: While Batman is pulling the brick from the wall Gordon speaks the line "Whatever you're going to do, you'd better do it fast, we've just found out who his next victim will be, he's put it in tomorrow's paper." then he shows batman the paper with the mayor's picture with Joker paint on it, under the headline for the service.  So yes, they knew exactly when the Joker was going to attack because he told them.

Comment: He knew that there would be *an* attack on the mayor. They did not know the exact method of attack.

Comment: They didn't know the method, but they did know that the Joker was going to attack at the funeral.

Comment: @Robert, why at the funeral? The Joker already killed a judge at the door of her house and the police commissioner at his own office. He personally attacked Dent at his fundraiser party in the penthouse of the city's wealthiest guy. It was obvious that the mayor would be at the funeral, but seeing the other two, he could have suffered an assassination attempt anywhere, so then Gordon would have need to be prepared to feign his death in every situation possible.

Comment: Yes. So if a bomb had exploded or poisonous gas filled the area, Gordon may not be in the exact spot to safely fake his death, or even be able to survive the attack. If the bullet came from another angle, he may not be in the right spot.

Comment: @Deion, you're asking why the Joker attacked at Loeb's funeral?  The Joker made it a point to kill high profile people in very public ways.  The mayor would be out in the open in front of thousands of people.  For someone trying to assassinate someone, that's like having Christmas come early.  If you're asking why wouldn't he attack the mayor at home?  That I don't know because that would actually make perfect sense to mislead the police and Batman.

Comment: @phantom42 yes, if a bomb and detonated, the entire plan would have been screwed.  But they were taking a chance.  Gordon's task was to protect the mayor, that much was clear.  Regardless of from which angle the bullet came from Gordon was going to take it.  If it killed him he'd have done his duty and saved the mayor.  If it hadn't killed him and he hadn't faked his death, he would have still been promoted to commissioner in a public way.

Comment: At which point, the Joker would have needed to get rid of Gordon.  The Joker was not above attacking someone's family to kill them.  Gordon knew this to be true.  Besides, even if the Joker didn't attack his family at first and continued to fail at killing Gordon, he would have eventually gone after them.  Gordon being publicly promoted to commissioner would have placed him and his family on the Joker's radar

Comment: What I'm saying is something like what @phantom42 explained. Gordon could not know the method. He could not know when or if he would get a chance to pretend to be dead. he would have had to prepare for everything, on his own, since he wanted to play it close to the chest.

Comment: Are we sure he had a plan? I always envisioned him truly getting shot and then pulling the same trick that Nick Fury did in Cap2: getting the doctors to declare him dead, making the most of an unexpected opportunity. The idea could have formed when he woke up (or was resuscitated) in the hospital, more of a "just don't tell anyone I woke up" sort of thing. In that case, there wouldn't have been a long-term plan, he would have just been biding his time, calling in favors with people he could trust, and waiting for an opportunity to turn the tables on the Joker. No proof, but its how I read it.

Comment: @Deion, I've addressed that issue.  Gordon's mission was to protect the mayor, plain and simple.  Gordon knew that if he succeeded, he would receive a very public promotion to commissioner, placing himself and his family on the Joker's radar.  He definitely didn't want to die, but he was going to protect the mayor, if the attack killed him, he would have done his duty, if it didn't, he would need to make it appear as though he did to protect himself and his family.  This is something he repeats a few times after the funeral.

Comment: Each time a character addresses this, he blatantly says, "I couldn't risk my family."  He knew that if he saved the mayor and lived, the Joker would be gunning for him.

Comment: @Robert, don't take it personal. I'm not saying that your theory is not good or that is not possible. I'm just pointing out that Gordon needed to be 5 steps ahead of everything. After Loeb and Surillo's deaths, there is no warranty of anything, even if the funeral parade seems the best chance to feign his death for Gordon. I just wanted to add that to expand the original question: "what was Gordon's original plan", to point that Gordon's idea might be not "feign death at the parade" but "feign death at the first chance".

Comment: @Nerrolken The original plan may have not included getting shot at the funeral, but he clearly had *some* sort of plan in action, even if it was only conceived after being "killed".

Comment: @phantom42, if Gordon couldn't get a chance of being killed, maybe he could still have pretended to be the van driver anyway (nobody checked the ID of that swat driver?). So I think we are giving to much importance to the "being killed: feign death" part of the plan to answer this question. Gordon possibly could have gone along with other parts of the plan or other plan if needed.

Comment: @Deion, I'm not taking it personal or offensive.  We've got different theories on the subject, I respect that.  I'm more interested in the different view points we all have on it as, in reality, it's really left up to the viewer to make his/her own determination about what actually was happening 'behind the scenes'.

Answer (score 5):

I think Gordon's plan was to lure the Joker out so that the real Batman could take him down.  As the Joker said, he actually thought that Dent was Batman because of the interaction in Bruce's penthouse.  Plus the Joker was still trying to get Dent, so if he could kill him during the convoy attack, he's getting rid of two birds with one stone, so to speak.  Gordon also didn't want his family to be placed in the line of fire, the police commissioner had just been killed and Gordon was obviously the next person in line for the job.  This is something he knew, so, instead of placing a target on his family, he faked his death so that the Joker would believe that the police had no leader.  I think that Bruce did know of the plan and that it was just he and Gordon who knew.  Remember, Gordon didn't trust anyone in the police department, which left Batman as the only person he did trust.

I think that Bruce's desire to turn himself in was genuine and was actually going against the plan that he and Gordon has established.  If Bruce had succeeded in turning himself in, the plan would have been ruined and there never would have been a convoy for the Joker to attack as he wasn't interested in taking Batman out.

Gordon probably would have stayed in hiding for as long as it took to catch the Joker. If you remember, he didn't reveal himself to everyone until he saw his opportunity. Had Batman not shown up during the attack and the convoy escaped, chances are, Gordon would have still been in hiding. But the Joker got distracted and Gordon saw his chance to finally capture him.

Comment: If Bruce knew about the plan why was he there as Batman, hiding in shadows, when the policemen went to tell Ms. Gordon about the news?

Comment: Perhaps to put on a charade in case someone saw him.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. You say that the Joker thought Dent was Batman and was still trying to get him, but that the Joker wouldn't have attacked the convoy if he thought Batman was in the convoy.

Comment: When Batman is interrogating the Joker, the Joker says "you know, for a while there, I really thought you were Dent, the way you threw yourself after her."  Referencing the attack at Bruce's penthouse.  The Joker's attack on the convoy was strictly to kill Harvey Dent not Batman, in fact, it's made clear that the Joker doesn't really care who Batman is.  If Bruce had turned himself in, there would be no Batman to get in his way, as you said.  Therefore, Harvey wouldn't have even been in the convoy and would have been attacked at a different location.

Comment: I don't understand either how could have Gordon known that at some point the Joker would come out, or that someone (Dent) would provide such a good opportunity for the Joker to attack. Also, too much to assume that Batman was in the same page as Gordon with all that, specially after Alfred and Bruce's conversation in the bunker. Batman has other things in minds that going along with someone else's plan.

Comment: If the convoy had been transporting Bruce, they would have gotten from point a to point b without an attack.  As I said, the Joker thought that Dent and batman were one in the same, but he had no interest in killing Batman, but if killing Dent would also kill the Batman, so be it.  Either way, the Joker would have attacked Dent that night because a)Batman would have been in jail and wouldn't be able to interfere.  Or b)Batman was about to be killed when Harvey was killed.

Comment: @September, remember the scene prior when they discover when and where the Joker is going to attack the mayor?  It's not on screen, but it's a safe assumption that they drew up that plan at that point in time.  Granted that's entirely speculation on my part because I have no evidence to back it up.  But also remember, Bruce analyzed the fingerprint from what Lucius gave him.  Again, he knew the Joker was going to attack during the parade and he knew who he was going to attack.  Gordon had a pretty substantial detail set up to prevent the attack and was looking for the Joker the entire time.

Comment: Also, both Bruce and Gordon had the mission to prevent the mayor from being killed.  It only makes sense that they would combine resources to stop the killing and capture the Joker at the same time.

Comment: After re-reading like 8 times, I think I finally understand what you're trying to say: the Joker wanted *Dent* specifically. This, however, still leaves the question unanswered: how long would Gordon have remained in hiding?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I'm sorry if I worded it horribly.  Gordon probably would have stayed in hiding for as long as it took to catch the Joker.  If you remember, he didn't reveal himself to everyone until he saw his opportunity.  Had Batman not shown up during the attack and the convoy escaped, chances are, Gordon would have still been in hiding.  But the Joker got distracted and Gordon saw his chance to finally capture him.

Comment: @phantom42 I've edited my answer to reflect what my previous comment said, hopefully that makes it more clear.